# What is the difference between "could've" and "could of"?

Tags: differences, word-usage, tenses, past-tense

I have seen people using *could of* instead of *could have*. Are both of them correct?  Is there a difference in meaning between them?

Comment: "Could of" is a misrepresentation of "could've", which is a contraction of "could have", which is where you started. "Could of" is not yet acceptable (and drives some people mad when they see it).

Comment: I hope could of never gets a foothold in English...not even informal...has it already?

Comment: @michael_timofeev u could of seen it alot by now if u r on Facebook n read the comments their.

Comment: (man, was that painful to write.)

Comment: Lol...I can't bear to see some of the English used there.

Comment: "could of" is usually used by uneducated American teenagers.

Comment: This is a spelling issue, of approximately the same importance for the future of mankind as the correct spelling of _theatre_ or _emphasize_. In the real language there is no difference between _could've_ and _could of_ and _could have_; they're all pronounced the same and understood the same. It's only folks whose sensitivities to spelling were permanently overstimulated in grade school who worry about this. To an English learner, it's irrelevant because it doesn't affect speech.

Answer (score 22):

"Could of" is ***always wrong***.

It's just that the contracted "have" in "could've" *sounds like* "of", so uneducated people started writing it as "of" too.

(For the record, "should of", "would of", "might of", and the like are also always wrong.)

Comment: @Hellion, sorry to say that a lot of *educated* people write "could of" as well.  And I've heard people *saying* it ... "I ate the last of the pie" / "Well you shouldn't of" ... with the "of" fully pronounced.

Comment: I'd add the hedge that the words _could_ and _of_ can legitimately end up together, though not in that meaning; the _of_ can be part of a phrase like "of course" or "of one's own free will".

Comment: @hemflit I could, of course, write *could* and *of* together like that, but I could not come up with a case that did not call for a comma between them.  :-)

Comment: @DavidGarner Normally when I hear people *say* it, I assume they're saying the double contraction *shouldn't've* instead, which makes more sense and sounds identical in some dialects.

Comment: @Geobits It seems *shouldn't've's* got a lot of apostrophes.

Comment: @talrnu Sure, I wouldn't've written it that way except to illustrate the point, but people say it like that all the time (at least in the US).

Comment: @Geobits So you're saying *shouldn't've'sn't* a problem. I agree!

Comment: @Hellion, "Could one do X at all?" - "One could of one's own will, but not by force."

Comment: I write "shouldn't've, and I think it works as a natural extension of "shouldn't" and "should've".

Comment: My only regret is that I have but one +1 to give for this answer.

Comment: I'd be wary of saying it's "wrong". Language is a societal construct, after all, so if "could of" is mutually intelligible by the parties in the conversation then there's no "wrong" to it. Pedantry on the subject is foolish, as English (like any other language) will evolve no matter how pundits "feel" about the new constructs.

Comment: @DavidGarner "*I've heard people saying it ... "I ate the last of the pie" / "Well you shouldn't of" ... with the "of" fully pronounced.*" Yes, exactly so! I was just talking about that [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/383911/how-many-legitimate-uses-of-could-of-would-of-should-of-are-there/383927#383927) !

Answer (score 4):

Technically speaking, the phrase "could of" (in this context) arose from a mishearing of the contraction "could've" (as Hellion points out) and the literal definition of the words does not convey the intended meaning behind the phrase "could have". This is called a malapropism: "the mistaken use of a word in place of a similar-sounding one" (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism)).

With that said, language is not a set of "right" and "wrong". It evolves as our habits do, and things that were once considered "wrong" can become the accepted way of speaking and writing, even in the most formal settings. For example, the word "apron" used to be spelled "napron" -- but because the phrase "mine napron" was so common, the word was misheard so frequently that it eventually changed. That and several other examples of malapropisms that entered the English language are written about in [this guardian article](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/mar/11/pronunciation-errors-english-language).

Recent printed usage of "could of" [is nothing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=could+have%2Ccould+of&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccould%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20of%3B%2Cc0) compared to "could have". In professional and formal settings, using the phrase "could have" is definitely preferable.

Comment: I don't think _mine napron_ in particular was ever all that much more common than it is now. Rather, it is the relative _non_-commonness of the word _apron_ in general, combined mostly with the indefinite article _a(n)_ (but yes, also with the possessive determiners) that bungled things up. When the final /n/ was lost in _an_ as well as _mine/thine_, things like _anapron_ became ambiguous: is it _a napron_ or _an apron_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet i agree that your speculation seems very likely, but i think that i will leave the answer as written since that example comes directly from the article i cited in the following sentence.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow: A fellow descriptivist! Oh frabjous day! Callooh! Callay! The English language loses a tiny bit of poetry every time someone corrects a mutually intelligible shift in an utterance.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow ,  EL&U is a site for language lawyers to discuss such distinctions and to come up with the currently acceptable usage.  "It's a malaprop" could be the answer to nearly every question on the site, but that's generally not the answer the questioners are seeking.